# How to see dom tree for specific component in JSX React

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have the following code in my component:

renderName: function(name) {
      return (
        
          {name}
        
      )
    }

then in `render` method I want to inspect what will be HTML DOM representation of running this method:

```
render: function() {
  let namePart = this.renderName('Berlin');
  ...
}
```

How can I see code

```
<div>
   Berlin
</div>
```

Maybe there is some method for compiling this object that I can see during inspection in DevTools into HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference `this` in React, one way is to use

`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)`

Here are the docs on it.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

**ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)**

> If this component has been mounted into the DOM, this returns the corresponding native browser DOM element. This method is useful for reading values out of the DOM, such as form field values and performing DOM measurements. In most cases, you can attach a ref to the DOM node and avoid using findDOMNode at all.

It suggests using `refs` if you need to avoid using findDOMNode.